# Save form in model django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, save

im trying to save the data of a form in my model on Django, but when I submit the form and I see the Django admin page, there are any changes.

forms.py:

```
class PublisherForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Publisher
        fields = ['name','address','city','state_province','country','website']

form = PublisherForm #Creating a form to add a Publisher
```

Here is my view.py

```
def add_publisher(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PublisherForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_publisher=form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            print form.errors
    else:
        form = PublisherForm()
    return render_to_response('add_publisher.html', {'form':form})
```

and my models.py:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Anybody can help me?

Comment: Please edit your question and fix the indenting. It's hard to tell where the problem might be at the moment. After `if form.is_valid():`, try putting `print form.errors` in an `else` block -- that might tell you where the problem is.

Comment: @Alasdair Sorry , I just correct the indentation . I added the else block that you have suggested to me but the page does not return any error. Thank you

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting a CSRF form when you submit the post request. I suggest changing the last line of the view to `return render(request,  'add_publisher.html', {'form':form})` (you'll need to add the import).

Comment: Make sure you form has `method="post"`. Could you add your template to the question?

Comment: @Alasdair Just solved my problem . The problem was it was not filling out the form correctly , as it was entering an e -mail on a URLField field (). I do not understand it because I did not throw the error on the page. Although I could see on the console.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Great, glad you solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**offtopic**, but this is little bit easier way to use form.

```
def add_publisher(request):
    form = PublisherForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
        new_publisher = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    return render_to_response('add_publisher.html', {'form':form})
```